# how to get all collection names from a specific db in mongo using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Recently I want to get all collection names from a db in mongo. And my develop environment is nodejs + express + mongoose. I tried *mongooser.conncetion.db.getCollectionNames(or listCollections or collections)*, but any does not work. I guess the it is the version problem, maybe the latest mongoose api does not contain those functions.

Consequently, how to obtain all collection names from a db using mongoose?

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: You forgot to list the versions for your tech stack.

Comment: Can you add some code? I test it, listCollections works find. Warn: listCollections return a cursor.

Comment: var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
    mongoose.connection.db.listCollections(function (err, names) {
        console.log(names); 
    });
}); //my mongoose version is 3.9.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get collections list in mongoose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254813/how-get-collections-list-in-mongoose)