# How get collections list in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How I can get names collection list in mongoose?
Older answers -
mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames is not a function (

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Indeed, `mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames` was dropped in favor of `mongoose.connection.db.listCollections`.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connection = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017');

connection.on('open', function () {
    connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(names);
      }

      mongoose.connection.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: how can I list collections of another database?

Answer (score 3):

if you just want an array containing the collection names then you can use

```
const collections = Object.keys(mongoose.connection.collections);
```

and you get a result like this

```
[
  "identitycounters",
  "roles",
  "user"
]
```

depending on what's in your db.

Answer (score 1):

To get collections now it's:`connection.db.collections`.